# Outlook add-in creating spurious folders in new PSTs

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I'm maintaining an Outlook 2010 addin produced by my company. Some of our clients have reported that spurious folders named `&Dont prompt me about this again.`, `&Dont prompt me about this again.1`, `&Dont prompt me about this again.2`, etc. are appearing. I was able to duplicate this issue by creating a new PST file; each time I re-open Outlook, a new folder is created.

Some research indicates that people have reported similar issues with Outlook Social Connector and the Norton Antispam Outlook Addin. I verified that neither of the above is causing our issue. It seems to me that this is an issue among Outlook add-ins. Is there something we can do to fix it in our Outlook add-in?

Comment: Seems to me like whoever "produced" that addin at your company had some bad intentions.

Comment: Hah. I don't think that's it at all. This seems to be a common issue with Outlook 2010 add-ins.

Comment: You're right. I found a couple of reports on Microsoft Support and Technet. No solution though in either of those posts unfortunately. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/dont-prompt-me-about-this-again/1c049173-41d6-42bd-b319-5670704eba6e

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the method 'GetDefaultFolder' with any value, if the folder doesn't exist in the new .pst file, the Outlook create it:

```
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = OutlookApp.Session;
    Outlook.Store store = ns.Stores[1];
    store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
```

Sometimes, for no reason, the Outlook creates strange folders, like in my question:
[Outlook.Store.GetDefaultFolder creates a stranger folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790507/outlook-store-getdefaultfolder-outlook-is-creating-strange-folders-in-a-new-pst)

I'm still dont understand why...