# Outlook.Store.GetDefaultFolder Outlook is creating strange folders in a new .pst file

Tags: c#, com, outlook-addin, office-addins, comaddin

After creating a new .pst file only 2 folders are created with the new Outlook.Store(.pst).

Example 1:

[image: New .pst]

After you close Outlook and reopen it, several folders are created.
Some are standard folders, such as Recycle Bin, RSSFeed, and more. But some are strange and have strange names (with strange characters).

Example 2:

[image: New Folders]

When I was debugging the routine of my COM Addin I have identified that in Addin's 'Startup' event, there is a code that checks the default folders of the Outlook.Store.

The 'GetDefaultFolder' method of the Outlook.Store object is used. This method is recommended by Microsoft to identify the default folders of an Outlook.Store.

When this method is executed, depending on the parameter, it creates the folder in Outlook.Store. I created a simple COM Addin to exemplify:

In the Startup event I did this:

```
        private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("##Log##");

        //Startup
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = OutlookApp.Session;
        Outlook.Store lastStore = ns.Stores[1];//Just to get the new Store

        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderConflicts);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJournal);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderLocalFailures);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderManagedEmail);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderNotes);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderRssFeeds);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderServerFailures);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSuggestedContacts);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSyncIssues);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderToDo);
        GetDefaultFolder(lastStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sb.ToString());

        private void GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.Store newStore, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders olFolderKind)
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder rootFolder = null;

        rootFolder = newStore.GetRootFolder();
        sb.AppendLine($"qtd: {rootFolder.Folders.Count}");

        try
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"Folder kind: {olFolderKind.ToString()}");
            newStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderKind);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"qtd: {rootFolder.Folders.Count}");
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine();
            
            if (rootFolder != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rootFolder);
        }
    }
```

I load the new .pst file (Outlook.Store) and fetch all default folders. But in a few cases new Folders are added.

The log of this code is:

### Log

Ex

qtd: 1
Folder kind: olFolderCalendar
qtd: 2

qtd: 2
Folder kind: olFolderConflicts
qtd: 2

qtd: 2
Folder kind: olFolderContacts
qtd: 3

qtd: 3
Folder kind: olFolderDeletedItems
qtd: 3

qtd: 3
Folder kind: olFolderDrafts
qtd: 4

qtd: 4
Folder kind: olFolderInbox
qtd: 4

qtd: 4
Folder kind: olFolderJournal
qtd: 5

qtd: 5
Folder kind: olFolderJunk
qtd: 6

qtd: 6
Folder kind: olFolderLocalFailures
qtd: 6

qtd: 6
Folder kind: olFolderManagedEmail
qtd: 6

qtd: 6
Folder kind: olFolderNotes
qtd: 7

qtd: 7
Folder kind: olFolderOutbox
qtd: 8

qtd: 8
Folder kind: olFolderRssFeeds
qtd: 9

qtd: 9
Folder kind: olFolderSentMail
qtd: 9

qtd: 9
Folder kind: olFolderServerFailures
qtd: 9

qtd: 9
Folder kind: olFolderSuggestedContacts
qtd: 9

qtd: 9
Folder kind: olFolderSyncIssues
qtd: 9

qtd: 9
Folder kind: olFolderTasks
qtd: 10

qtd: 10
Folder kind: olFolderToDo
qtd: 10

qtd: 10
Folder kind: olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders
qtd: 10

### Questions

What is this strange folder created by Outlook?
Why is the Outlook.Store.GetDefaultFolder method creating folders?
Is there another method that can be used that returns the same information as the GetDefaultFolder but DOES NOT create folders?

Answer (score 1):

The [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `Store` or `Namespace` class doesn't and shouldn't create folders in Outlook.

First of all, I see a custom add-ins running in Outlook (DocSite). Before creating any test with OOM I'd suggest to disable all of them.

Also I see an interesting domain name configured in Outlook. Is it IMAP or Exchange profile? If so, I'd suggest configuring any SMTP mail box instead.

Is a custom store provider?

Comment: Have you find the cause? Is it a custom store provider or other add-ins?

Comment: Hi Eugene, I'm developing Docsite Addin using Addin Express. Yes, it's DocSite that creates folders, I created another addin just to simulate the incident. In fact, it is the 'Store.GetDefaultFolder' method that creates strange folders. 1 account is Exchange and the other is SMTP / POP. The new .pst file is not connected with ay account, I just created.  Do you think it's best to create a post in the Addin Express forum? Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: To create the 'Example' store I just did: File -> Account Settings -> Data Files -> Add. Than only 2 folders was created(Outlook default). In my addin, in the startup event I have some code that check the default folders of every store. When this method is executed, on startup, for my new Store, some kinds of Folders occurs an exeption and a Strage folders is created. I have no idea why this happend.

Comment: Try to create a simple SMTP account in Outlook without any add-ins registered and running in Outlook. Are you able to reproduce the issue in that case?

Comment: I did some tests like you said and the answer is no. It does not happen. Just happens when a new Outlook.Store(new .pst file) was created with no e-mail account associated.

Comment: Did you try to add a new store programmatically in your tests?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll try this now

Comment: I did and this situation still happens.

Comment: Have you disabled all add-ins before adding a new store?

Comment: I'm using the MS Office 13, with the MSOffice 16 It doesnt happens.

Comment: Yes, the only addin that I use is my example Addin, to simulate this situation. It's and Add-in Express com addin. You can download here: [link](apoio.facil.com.br/files/docsite/myaddin11.zip)

Comment: What code do you use for creating a store? Have you tried contacting ADX developers?

Comment: To create the Store I used https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/05/31/outlook-accounts-stores-folders-items/ this example from ADX.                      -    Outlook.Namespace.AddStoreEx

Comment: Yes, I create this topic on ADX Forum:   https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=14523&MID=74404#message74404